# Prove the convergence of a series of functions with different values for $x \in [k,k+1[$ and otherwise

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Consider the following series of function

$$\sum_{k \geq 1} u_k(x) \,\,\, \mathrm{with} \,\,\, u_k(x)= \begin{cases} 
    \frac{1}{k}  & x\in [k,k+1[ \\
      0 & \mathrm{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$

The partial sum function is the following

$$ S_N(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_k(x)= \begin{cases} 
    \frac{1}{k}  & x\in [k,k+1[ \,\,\, \mathrm{with} \,\,\, k=1,2,...,N \\
      0 & \mathrm{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$

How can I prove that the series converges to the following function $f:[1, \infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$?

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{k} \,\,\, \mathrm{if} \,\,\, x \in [k,k+1[$$

That is, how to prove rigorously that $$\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N(x)=f(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in [1,+\infty[$$

Comment: I think in the definition of $u_k(x)$ and $S_N(x)$, you may need to change the range to $[k,k+1\color{red}{[}$. Otherwise, if $x=2$ then $S_N(2)=u_1(2)+u_2(2)=1/1+1/2=3/2\ne1/k=1/2$.

Comment: @HazemOrabi Thanks a lot, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
& f(x)=\frac{1}{k}\,\colon x\in[k,k+1[ \space\Rightarrow\space \color{red}{f(x)=\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}} \space\colon x\in[1,\infty[ \\[4mm]
& \text{Define}\quad {\large I}_{\small a}^{\small b}(x) = \begin{cases} 1  &\colon x\in[a,b[ \\[2mm] 0 &\space \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \\[4mm]
& u_k(x) = \frac{1}{k} \cdot {\large I}_{\small k}^{\small k+1}(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \cdot {\large I}_{\small k}^{\small k+1}(x) \\[4mm]
& S_N(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{N} u_k(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}\, \sum_{k=1}^{N}{\large I}_{\small k}^{\small k+1}(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \cdot {\large I}_{\small 1}^{\small N}(x) \\[4mm]
& \Rightarrow \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} S_N(x)= \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} {\large I}_{\small 1}^{\small N}(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \cdot {\large I}_{\small 1}^{\small \infty}(x) \space\Rightarrow\space \color{red}{\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} S_N(x)=\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}} \space\colon x\in[1,\infty[ \\[4mm]
& \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\color{white}{\text{.}}
\end{align}
$$